# Moving a Tensorflow tensor from C to python

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, pybind11

Im currently working with a tensor on using the tensorflow c api. However i have created it and done the operations i wish to do to it. Now i want to move it into python to do further operations on it.

Im using the tensorflow c-api because it offers a functionality not availible in the python api. So my goal was to create the tensor in C, do my required operations then move it to python. However i cant find anyway to do this. My approach was to just create a python binding and return the tensor, however this will be the tensor in c rather then the python one i require. Does anyone know any way i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow's PyFunc op has code to convert the `tensor` to a `PyObject` which could be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/lib/core/py_func.cc)

An example to use this could be:

```
#include "tensorflow/python/lib/core/py_func.h"

Status TensorHandler::ExportTensorAsNumpy(const Tensor *inputTensor) {
    PyObject* numpyObject = Py_None;
    tensorflow::ConvertTensorToNdarray(*inputTensor, &numpyObject);

    //process the numpy further its now stored in numpyObject

    //call this when you don't use the numpyObject anymore
    Py_DECREF(numpyObject);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. Can you please provide a little more detail to how I would actually convert a TF_Tensor to something I can use in python as a tensor?

Comment: Edited to give an example, look above

Comment: Thanks for the help, thats a great answer.